# Remove row names using capture.output in R?

Tags: r

This question is similar to [R: Format output of write.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163938/r-format-output-of-write-table), and 42-'s answer works except I need to remove row names. `capture_output` doesn't seem to have an equivalent of `row.names = FALSE`. I've also tried `row.names(aa) <- NULL` prior to running `capture.output`, but that doesn't help.

Is it possible to generate a right-justified text file just like `capture.output` does below, but with no row names?

```
aa = matrix(c(1000,110,10,1, 
            0,2000,20,2, 
            30,300,3000,30000), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE,
            dimnames = list(NULL, c("C1", "C2", "C3","C4")))
aa<-as.data.frame(aa)
aa

capture.output( print(aa, print.gap=3), file="capture.txt")
```

`write.fwf` doesn't right-justify as desired:

```
write.fwf(aa, "fwf.txt", rownames=FALSE, sep="\t", quote=FALSE, justify = "right")
```

Thank you!

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output? Are you trying to generate a fixed-width output file?

Comment: I want a text file formatted exactly as produced in the example code using capture.output, but without row names. I tried write.fwf with justify = "right", but the output ends up being only "half" right-justified. Adding more spaces with sep="\t\t" didn't fix that issue

Comment: Can't you just include `row.names=F` in your `print` statement? For example: `capture.output( print(aa, print.gap=3, row.names = F), file="capture.txt")`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I was putting it in the wrong spot

Comment: @Ben, do you want to post an answer for me to accept or should I just delete this question?

Comment: Thanks so much! what a silly oversight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the row names, use `row.names = FALSE` directly within the `print` statement:

```
capture.output(print(aa, print.gap=3, row.names = FALSE), file="capture.txt")
```

Output of `capture.txt`:

```
     C1     C2     C3      C4
   1000    110     10       1
      0   2000     20       2
     30    300   3000   30000
```